# Function that takes a list of multiple strings and tuples

Tags: python

So, I want to create a function that takes a list of multiple strings and tuples, and what it does is, if its a string, it just prints the string, but if its a tuple, the tuple takes an integer and a string and it multiplies them.

Example:

```
print(something(["1stString", "2ndString", (3, "Pie"), (4, "Soda")]))
```

and it prints:

```
1stString
2ndString
Pie
Pie
Pie
Soda
Soda
Soda
Soda
```

My miserable attempt:

```
def something(s):
    for x in s:
        if isinstance(s, str):
            print(s)
        if isinstance(s, tuple):
            x = tuple[0] * tuple[1]
        print(x)
    exit()
```

This works for the strings but not for the tuples.

It prints out:

```
1stString
2ndString
(3, 'Pie')
(4, 'Soda')
```

What am I doing wrong?

One more thing.
How about if I want it to print it out as a list?

Like this:

```
['1stString', '2ndString', 'Pie', 'Pie', 'Pie', 'Soda', 'Soda', 'Soda', 'Soda']
```

Answer (score 2):

As NPE said you are checking s not x. 
s is the whole list of elements while x is a placeholder for the current element of s.

```
def something(s):
    for x in s:
        if isinstance(x, str):
            print(x)
        if isinstance(x, tuple):
            for i in range(x[0]):
                print x[1]
```

Comment: Ahhh, that explains alot, it works now, thank you very much. Im still new to this langugage and I'm still figuring out how it works.

Comment: in the 2nd if, an "elif" would be slightly faster.

Comment: Would be better to use: `isinstance(obj, basestring)` So you can detect both str/unicode

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you're checking `s` and not `x` in `isinstance`:

```
isinstance(s, ...
```

I should also point out that this style of programming is very un-Pythonic. Perhaps if you explained why you're doing this, we might be able to improve on this approach.

Comment: Tell the teacher that a random person on the Internet says that they are teaching you bad habits :)

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.2:

```
    def something(s):
            for i in s:
               if isinstance(i,str):
                    print(i)
            else:
                print(i[0]*i[1])
```

it will print

```
    1stString
    2ndString
    PiePiePie
    SodaSodaSodaSoda
```

Comment: No it won't, it will just complain about the very odd indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a generator function:

```
def yielder(sequ):
    for E in sequ:
        if isinstance(E,str):
            yield E
        else:
            ss = E[1]
            for i in xrange(E[0]):
                yield ss

li = ["1stString", "2ndString", (3, "Pie"), (4, "Soda")]

print li
print '----------------------------'
print list(yielder(li))
print '----------------------------'
print '\n'.join(yielder(li))
```

result

```
['1stString', '2ndString', (3, 'Pie'), (4, 'Soda')]
----------------------------
['1stString', '2ndString', 'Pie', 'Pie', 'Pie', 'Soda', 'Soda', 'Soda', 'Soda']
----------------------------
1stString
2ndString
Pie
Pie
Pie
Soda
Soda
Soda
Soda
```